# Casting jlong to and from unsigned long int

Tags: java, c, casting, java-native-interface, unsigned

I have the following JNI function:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL foo(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jlong id, jlongArray array)
{
    jboolean isCopy;
    jsize len = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, array);
    jlong* lp = (*env)->GetLongArrayElements(env, array, &isCopy);
    if (!lp) {
        return INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;
    }

    jlong retval = 0;
    // insert code to cast id from jlong to ULONG before passing to bar(...)?
    jint ret = bar(id, &retval);
    if(len>=1) {
        // insert code to cast retval from ULONG back to jlong
        lp[0] = retval;
    }

    int mode = 0;
    // if error code is returned then do not save changes
    if(ret != 0) {
        mode = JNI_ABORT;
    }
    (*env)->ReleaseLongArrayElements(env, array, lp, mode);

    return ret;
}
```

Method `bar` has the signature

```
int bar(ULONG id, ULONG *val);
```

where `ULONG` is

```
typedef ULONG unsigned long int;
```

So in my JNI function I would like to cast parameter `id` from `jlong` to `ULONG`, and then `retval` from `ULONG` back to `jlong`. Can I directly cast, or is there a series of bitwise operations that I can do in these two cases?

Comment: [`jlong` is a signed 64-bit integer value](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html).  `unsigned long` is 32-bits on many platforms, even 64-bit Windows.  You probably should use `int64_t`, as in `int bar( int64_t id, int64_t *val );  Or just use `jlong`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I know about `jlong` being what it is, but unfortunately I cannot change `bar(...)`. Everything else is available for change.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this solution is a hack, but maybe you can go via `String`.

`java.util.Long` provides method to create unsigned String value from `long`:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#toUnsignedString-long-

It means, you can always convert your long value (assuming that you make sure it's not negative and in the range of `unsigned long`) to `String`, pass it to `JNI` based code, and convert it back.

**Java**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    long value_min = 0;
    // I assume that we are dealing with 32bit unsigned long on a C side
    // if you try to test boundary case with 4294967296L it fill fail for
    // 64bit macOS/Linux as you will be able to fit the value into variable.
    long value_max = 4294967295L;

    System.out.println("I am passing: " + value_min);
    PassLongAsString.passULong(java.lang.Long.toUnsignedString(value_min));

    System.out.println("I am passing: " + value_max);
    PassLongAsString.passULong(java.lang.Long.toUnsignedString(value_max));
  }
```

**C**

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_recipeNo058_PassLongAsString_passULong
  (JNIEnv * env, jclass obj, jstring str) {

  //we have to get string bytes into C string
  const char *c_str;

  c_str = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars (env, str, NULL);

  if (c_str == NULL) {
    return;
  }
  printf ("Passed string: %s\n", c_str);
  unsigned long ul = strtoul (c_str, NULL, 0);
  printf ("Parsed value:  %lu\n", ul);

  //after using it, remember to release the memory
  (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars (env, str, c_str);
}
```

Of course, it will fail if you will pass value